# Google Docs file upload limit

Tags: google-drive, upload

I am trying to load a 1.8 MB .docx file into Google Docs and getting the following message:

> This file could not be imported because it is over the 1 MB limit.

I have no idea why this may be, because according to Google I am:

> currently using 1 MB (0%) of your 21504 MB

They also say:

> You can upload files up to 1024 MB. Files converted to Google Docs have smaller limits.

Googling that error message did not help.

Comment: This is crazy! Not being able to import most of my documents is a major setback to adoption of the platform.

Answer (score 4):

actually it's enough to uncheck "convert to google document" and upload it in the original format without conversion.

Changing the filename did not work for me when I renamed to ".jpg" and then renamed the uploaded document back. I could upload and rename, but the filetype was still identified as "jpeg" and on download the file extension was reset to "jpg" (which could be quite confusing for other people you share it with)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google docs have smaller limits

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603

> Documents: 1,024,000 characters, regardless of the number of pages or font size. Uploaded document files that are converted to the Google documents format can’t be larger than 2 MB.

Comment: Current limit is 50 MB.

Answer (score 1):

The error message refers to the size of the specific .docx file that you are trying to upload. You are seeing that message probably because you have the checkbox next to "Convert documents, presentations, spreadsheets, and drawings to the corresponding Google Docs formats" checked. As you are trying to upload **as well as convert**, Google throws that error as it can only convert .docx files that are up to 1MB per file.

Assuming you just want to upload & not convert it to Google Document format, uncheck the "Convert documents, presentations, spreadsheets, and drawings to the corresponding Google Docs formats" option & you will be able to upload that 1.8MB docx file.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.  Change the file extension to one that isn't a document format, upload the file, then change the extension back once the file is uploaded